# Where should I store the JWT on the local computer (and how)?

Tags: c, authentication, jwt

I am programming a Snake Game in C with a ranking list, login and registration.  But I don`t know where I should save the JWT. It has not to be incredible secure (since it is just a little game), but it should still be secure. Since it is the first time that I am working with JWT in C I do not have much experience in this field.

Until now I saved the JWT (in plain text) in a file (called jwt) in a folder (which I called Snake) in APPDATA.

Comment: On machines like linux, you would probably like to store it in a hidden folder (folder/file names starting with `.`), which will not be listed unless explicitly requested by the user. This actually is not a kind of protection from hackers, it just is a method provided by unix to hide configuration files from being shown, so as to keep user's  folders clean. Many people don't even try to read them. I think it is true for mac as well.

Comment: And for a snakegame, if you really want to give your program some protection, you could introduce a very simple encode/decode function to save/read the data in your program's config files. The encoder/decoder could be very simple, like converting ASCII to their numbers (has a very straightforward approach in C). I think you may not need to have more protection than that in just a snakegame?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's ok to store the JWTs as a file on your disk. Compare with modern web browsers, all the secrets, and cookies stored in the browser are also not stored in a secure way.

If a hacker hacks your machine, it's pretty much game over, whatever you do.

It is all about what threat you want to be secure against and what is the risk?